# golang: how to release a net.Conn from a bfio.Reader

Tags: networking, go, buffer

In go I have a net.Conn that I wrap with a bufio.Reader. I want to read and parse certain number of lines from the reader, and then obtain back the control over the net.Conn, obtaining back all the temporary data the reader might still have buffered. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the buffered data from a `*bufio.Reader` using the following code:

```
 p, _ := br.Peek(br.Buffered())
```

where `p` is a `[]byte` containing the buffered data and `br` is a `*bufio.Reader`.

Many applications use the `*bufio.Reader` as an `io.Reader` after calling `ReadLine` and related methods. There's no need to get the buffered data in these applications.  The reader will continue reading from the buffered data as needed.